# SFML Button Not Working

Tags: c++, sfml

Under my button class, I have this function that checks if the mouse is within the bounds of the button:

```
bool Button::isMouseOver(int mousePosX, int mousePosY) {
    if (button.getPosition().x < mousePosX &&
        button.getPosition().x + button.getSize().x > mousePosX &&
        button.getPosition().y < mousePosY &&
        button.getPosition().y + button.getSize().y > mousePosY) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And then under my main cpp file I have this logic used to activate the function:

```
int mousePosX = sf::Mouse::getPosition().x;
int mousePosY = sf::Mouse::getPosition().y;

switch (Event.type) {

    case sf::Event::Closed:
        window.close();

    case sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed:
        if (btnPlay.isMouseOver(mousePosX, mousePosY)) {
            std::cout << "True\n";
        }
    }
```

but for some reason, nothing happens. And I know that this can work, because I have the same exact code in one of my other games and it works fine.

Comment: Why aren't you using a `break` statement for each case?

Comment: You should probably get mouse position relative to the window, not desktop. `sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);`

Comment: And use `mapPixelToCoords`: http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/graphics-view.php#coordinates-conversions

Comment: To debug it and verify the previous commenter's comments are correct add a `std::cout` of all of the coordinates in your `isMouseOver`so you can check what actually happens.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly off topic, you comment

> And I know that this can work, because I have the same exact code in
>   one of my other games and it works fine.

triggered me to think You might want to consider generalizing this and making something like

```
bool IsInside(windowPos wp, windowSize ws, someOtherPos sop) {
    if (wp.x < sop.X &&
        wp.x + ws.x > sop.X &&
        wp.y < sop.Y &&
        wp.y + ws.y > sop.Y) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool Button::isMouseOver(Vector2i mousePos) {
    return IsInside(getPosition(), getSize(), mousePos) ;
}
```

Note types in `IsInside` are not exact and might actually be the same ( `Vector2i` ).

This also makes testing easier for correctness and removes a source of errors with copied code.